# how do I set page width in wickedPDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm using wickedPDF to create pdfs in rails and all seems to be going well, until I try to put a full width image in. I want my width of the page to be 595px (a4 at 72dpi) however, if I set

```
body{
  width: 595px;
}
```

And a simple image tag with a width of 595px, it only fills 2/3s of the screen. If I change the width of the image to be 700px, it fills with entire screen.

My question is how do I change the width that WickedPDF generates, Here's what my PDf currently looks like:

```
format.pdf {
        render :pdf => "pdf_1",
               :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?,
               :layout => 'pdf.html',
               :template => "/pdfs/show_pdf",
               :margin => {:top                => 0,
                           :bottom             => 0,
                           :left               => 0,
                           :right              => 0},
               :orientation      => 'Portrait', # default , Landscape,
               :no_background    => true
      }
```

I've tried adding options like zoom and page width with no success, If i set `:dpi=>72` I get a blank screen so that's no good either

Comment: Yule, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Had to manually adjust all the widths

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can look at `:page_size => '...'` option. From man wkhtmltopdf

> -s, --page-size               Set paper size to: A4, Letter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I make .container div with 1200-1400px width, because had a wide table on the page. Inside put some div's with width=100%. It works fine for me, like some sort of zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need @Yule. I use this:

```
  <div style="width: 820px; margin: auto;">
    <%= render :partial => "pdf_partial" %>
  </div>
```

and I also have this in wicked_pdf.rb:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :page_size  => "Letter",
  :dpi => '300'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For margin options you can pass to wicked pdf which in turn will pass them to the binary:

options = { margin: { right: 0, left: 0, top: 0, bottom: 0 }

See

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/blob/master/test/unit/wicked_pdf_test.rb#L134